# Adding a percentage sign in Javascript

Tags: javascript, percentage

In Javascript I'm trying to add a % sign at the end of my function but I get NaN when I test it.

```
function percentReadyForDegree(creditsEarned) { 
    return Math.round((creditsEarned / 71) * 100 + "%");
}  

percentReadyForDegree(30);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass a number to `Math.round`. In your code you're passing a string. Add the sign **after** the operation:

```
return Math.round(creditsEarned / 71 * 100) +'%';
```